# A space is created above the element when scrolling from bottom to top on Chrome for Android

Tags: html, css, reactjs, google-chrome

I'm waiting for someone who's had the same experience as me.
When I was developing web site with React, the problem was occurred.

On Chrome for Android(the latest version), a space is created above the element when scrolling from bottom to top.

At the first, I thought it was occurred because of complex styling, external dependencies or something in my React app.

So I've tested like below

1. Created new React app by `npx create-react-app test`.
2. Didn't add any other dependencies excluding default dependencies created by CRA.
3. Create elements and add inline style. (now height of body is overflowed)
4. Scroll smoothly from bottom to top

And the same problem came out.

It seems a bug of Chrome for Android, but I want to know if there's a way to prevent this problem.
Also let me know what should I do if it's not a bug of browser.

[You can check the problem by video.](https://streamable.com/miesnf)

- OS: Android
- Browser: Chrome 111.0.5563.57

Answer (score 0):

I've also been having the same issue with my react-app.

I noticed this also happens when just doing a short scroll to the top of my page when I am almost at the top.

Space is getting added to the top part of my page, which results in screen distortions if you click a button on the top part of the page (triggers re-render).

For now this issue can be avoided by adding this css to the body:
overscroll-behavior: none;

Note: this will prevent the ability to refresh the page when pulling down on the screen in mobile